# How to use 'OR' in elasticsearch PHP

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have an index of places with street address, city, province, and postal code. Now I'm trying to use elastic search to use the 'OR' keyword like in MySQL. Here's my current code:

```
$query = 'Kassandraburgh';

$searchParams['index'] = 'listings';
$searchParams['type']  = 'property';



$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['term']['Address.City'] = $query;
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or'][]['term']['Address.StateOrProvince'] = $query;
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or'][]['term']['Address.FullStreetAddress'] = $query
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or'][]['term']['Address.PostalCode'] = $query;

$queryResponse = Es::search($searchParams); 

print_r($queryResponse);
```

I based my code on the documentation on the [OR filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html) But this doesn't seem to be working. As there's always 0 results returned when I do it. Any ideas what I am missing here? All of the fields are analyzed.

**Update**

Ok I made some progress. I can now query using the street address, city, postal code and state/province. But now the filters no longer work. In fact when I try to put in some filters elastic search doesn't return any results at all. Here's my current code:

$search_params['body']['query']['filtered']['query']['query_string']['query'] = 'Los Angeles';

```
$search_params['body']['query']['query_string']['fields'] = array(
            'Address.PostalCode', 
            'Address.FullStreetAddress',
            'Address.StateOrProvince',
            'Address.City',
); 


$search_params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['term']['Category'] = 'Awesome';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Term filter does not normally work on analyzed fields. Fields should be set as 'not_analyzed' for the `term` filter to be effective. You could use a `match` or other filter instead. Alternatively you can specify a `multi_field` mapping so you can store an `analyzed` and `not_analyzed` version in the same mapping.